# Звуки [ъ] и [ь]

Tags: фонетика, фонетический-разбор

Будьте добры, расскажите, как верно понимать, где находятся звуки [ъ] или [ь]. Дело в том, что в книге И.Б. Голуб "Секреты русского языка" в рассказе о многообразии звуков есть пример обозначения редуцированных гласных в русской фонетической транскрипции с помощью **ъ** и **ь**. Честно говоря, объяснения, представленные в книге, не все просты и иллюстрированы. Одна из иллюстраций: земля и земляной; *е* в транскрипции — [**и^э**] и [**ь**] соответственно. Как увидеть (услышать), что в слове холодно транскрипция [хо́л**ъ**дн**ъ**], а не [хо́лΛднΛ], и т. д.?

Comment: Звук **[ъ]** произносится как **сверхкраткий *[ы]***, а **[ь]** - как **сверхкраткий *[и]***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как увидеть (услышать), что в слове холодно транскрипция [хо́лъднъ], а не [хо́лΛднΛ], и т. д.?

Именно слушать. Только слушать. Если вы и все вокруг вас произносят не в соответствии с нормами или вы просто не различаете эти звуки, то и услышать не сможете. Мне поэтому и ответ Sibyll'ы не понравился. Ну можно запомнить, что одно в первом предударном. а другое - во втором, но в результате - как в том анекдоте. *Это нэвозможно понъйят, это надо запомныт*.

Если же вы слушаете орфоэпически правильную речь, то разберетесь. Возьмите какое-нибудь слово ***"колокольчик"***, например, и вы услышите, что все три О в нем произносятся по-разному.

***В первом слоге звук похож на очень краткое "Ы"***- именно так призносился в очень давние времена (века до XIII-XIII) *ер* - нынешний твердый знак. Потому его и выбрали в качестве транскрипционного символа. Аналогично и "ерь" (мягкий знак) после мягких согласных обозначает похожий звук - краткое И.

***Во втором слоге Λ - это  краткое А***. Он тоже слегка различается после мягких и твердых согласных, но гораздо меньше, чем Ъ и Ь в слогах второй степени редукции, обычное это различие двух вариантов на письме не обозначают.

***Ну а в третьем слоге - полноценное О.***

Научившись различать эти звуки, вы легко поймете, когда какой произносится, и все разговоры о "предударном и первом-втором заударном" не будут для вас догмой вроде нотной грамоты для глухого.

Comment: Спасибо, так намного понятней. Только странно: здесь (http://ask.fm/russian/answers/137341504828) говорят о том, что и ер, и ерь никогда в первом слоге не бывают.

Comment: Ерунду говорят. По ссылке попасть не могу - не пускают. Но сама по себе постановка абсурдная. А что там, если не ер, в словах с ударением на третий-четвертый-пятый слоги?  А то и на шестой - русский язык велик и могуч.  )))

Answer (score 1):

Из Интернета:
[http://uclg.ru/education/russkiy_yazik/5_klass/fonetika__grafika/lecture_[y]*i*[].html](http://uclg.ru/education/russkiy_yazik/5_klass/fonetika__grafika/lecture_[y]_i_[].html)

"Эти знаки в фонетической транскрипции обозначают безударные гласные **во втором и последующих предударных и заударных слогах**, которые претерпели сильную количественную и качественную редукцию". (Это вторая степень редукции).

"[ъ] («ер») обозначает такой гласный после **твёрдого согласного** (пароход [пърахот], замок [замък]), а [ь] («ерь») – после **мягкого** (пятачок [п’ьтач’ок], к детям [гд’эт’ьм]).

По основным характеристикам гласных звук [ъ] **среднего подъёма и среднего ряда**, нелабиализованный. Звук [ь] отличается от него только тем, что язык при его произнесении больше продвинут вперёд: он **переднего ряда**".

Земля - земли, [и^э] - первый предударный слог, первая степень рекдукции,   [ь] - заударный слог, вторая степень редукции.

[Хо́лъднъ] - заударные слоги, вторая степень редукции.

Comment: Несли человек не различает или не знает, как произносить, эти звуки, чем ему могут помочь сведения о степени редукции?    А если различает, то зачем телегу впереди лошади ставить, заставляя определять позицию раньше, чем сам звук?